# jQuery - Apply changes to element that matches variable number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, this

I have a list of elements that i want to check for a specific number of classes, if an element has 10 of these classes, i want something i that element to change.

So if the element ".card" continas 10 ".fa-heart", some text and classes needs to change in that element only. Right now it apply´s it to all of my element.

This is where i am right now

js code:

```
$( ".card .card-footer .btn" ).html( "Add heart" );

$(".card .card-user-points ul").each(function() {
    var countHearts = $(this).children('.fa-heart').length;
    console.log(countHearts);

    if(countHearts == 10) {
        $( ".card .card-footer .btn" ).html( "Give Coffee" );
        $(".card-wrapper").find( ".card .btn" ).addClass( "green" );
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="card-wrapper">

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-settings fa fa-cog"></div>
        <div class="card-header">
            <h1 class="user-name">Navn Navnsen</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="card-user-info">
            <p class="user-phone">Tlf.: 12345678</p>
            <p class="user-mail">mail: <a href="mailto:min@mail.dk">min@email.dk</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-user-points clearfix">
            <ul>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="card-user-stats clearfix">
            <p>Sidste klip</p>
            <p class="user-last-stamp">11/11/2014</p>

            <p>Samlet klip</p>
            <p class="user-total-stamps">147</p>

            <p>kopper givet</p>
            <p class="user-total-cups">14</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <div class="btn"></div> <a href="#" class="destructive-link"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-settings fa fa-cog"></div>
        <div class="card-header">
            <h1 class="user-name">Navn Navnsen</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="card-user-info">
            <p class="user-phone">Tlf.: 12345678</p>
            <p class="user-mail">mail: <a href="mailto:min@mail.dk">min@email.dk</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-user-points clearfix">
            <ul>
                <li class="fa fa-heart fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart fa-3x"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="card-user-stats clearfix">
            <p>Sidste klip</p>
            <p class="user-last-stamp">11/11/2014</p>

            <p>Samlet klip</p>
            <p class="user-total-stamps">147</p>

            <p>kopper givet</p>
            <p class="user-total-cups">14</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <div class="btn"></div> <a href="#" class="destructive-link"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-settings fa fa-cog"></div>
        <div class="card-header">
            <h1 class="user-name">Navn Navnsen</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="card-user-info">
            <p class="user-phone">Tlf.: 12345678</p>
            <p class="user-mail">mail: <a href="mailto:min@mail.dk">min@email.dk</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-user-points clearfix">
            <ul>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="card-user-stats clearfix">
            <p>Sidste klip</p>
            <p class="user-last-stamp">11/11/2014</p>

            <p>Samlet klip</p>
            <p class="user-total-stamps">147</p>

            <p>kopper givet</p>
            <p class="user-total-cups">14</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <div class="btn"></div> <a href="#" class="destructive-link"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-settings fa fa-cog"></div>
        <div class="card-header">
            <h1 class="user-name">Navn Navnsen</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="card-user-info">
            <p class="user-phone">Tlf.: 12345678</p>
            <p class="user-mail">mail: <a href="mailto:min@mail.dk">min@email.dk</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-user-points clearfix">
            <ul>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="card-user-stats clearfix">
            <p>Sidste klip</p>
            <p class="user-last-stamp">11/11/2014</p>

            <p>Samlet klip</p>
            <p class="user-total-stamps">147</p>

            <p>kopper givet</p>
            <p class="user-total-cups">14</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <div class="btn"></div> <a href="#" class="destructive-link"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-settings fa fa-cog"></div>
        <div class="card-header">
            <h1 class="user-name">Navn Navnsen</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="card-user-info">
            <p class="user-phone">Tlf.: 12345678</p>
            <p class="user-mail">mail: <a href="mailto:min@mail.dk">min@email.dk</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-user-points clearfix">
            <ul>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="card-user-stats clearfix">
            <p>Sidste klip</p>
            <p class="user-last-stamp">11/11/2014</p>

            <p>Samlet klip</p>
            <p class="user-total-stamps">147</p>

            <p>kopper givet</p>
            <p class="user-total-cups">14</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <div class="btn"></div> <a href="#" class="destructive-link"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-settings fa fa-cog"></div>
        <div class="card-header">
            <h1 class="user-name">Navn Navnsen</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="card-user-info">
            <p class="user-phone">Tlf.: 12345678</p>
            <p class="user-mail">mail: <a href="mailto:min@mail.dk">min@email.dk</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-user-points clearfix">
            <ul>
                <li class="fa fa-heart fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart fa-3x"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="card-user-stats clearfix">
            <p>Sidste klip</p>
            <p class="user-last-stamp">11/11/2014</p>

            <p>Samlet klip</p>
            <p class="user-total-stamps">147</p>

            <p>kopper givet</p>
            <p class="user-total-cups">14</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <div class="btn"></div> <a href="#" class="destructive-link"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-settings fa fa-cog"></div>
        <div class="card-header">
            <h1 class="user-name">Navn Navnsen</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="card-user-info">
            <p class="user-phone">Tlf.: 12345678</p>
            <p class="user-mail">mail: <a href="mailto:min@mail.dk">min@email.dk</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-user-points clearfix">
            <ul>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="card-user-stats clearfix">
            <p>Sidste klip</p>
            <p class="user-last-stamp">11/11/2014</p>

            <p>Samlet klip</p>
            <p class="user-total-stamps">147</p>

            <p>kopper givet</p>
            <p class="user-total-cups">14</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <div class="btn"></div> <a href="#" class="destructive-link"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-settings fa fa-cog"></div>
        <div class="card-header">
            <h1 class="user-name">Navn Navnsen</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="card-user-info">
            <p class="user-phone">Tlf.: 12345678</p>
            <p class="user-mail">mail: <a href="mailto:min@mail.dk">min@email.dk</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-user-points clearfix">
            <ul>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="card-user-stats clearfix">
            <p>Sidste klip</p>
            <p class="user-last-stamp">11/11/2014</p>

            <p>Samlet klip</p>
            <p class="user-total-stamps">147</p>

            <p>kopper givet</p>
            <p class="user-total-cups">14</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <div class="btn"></div> <a href="#" class="destructive-link"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-settings fa fa-cog"></div>
        <div class="card-header">
            <h1 class="user-name">Navn Navnsen</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="card-user-info">
            <p class="user-phone">Tlf.: 12345678</p>
            <p class="user-mail">mail: <a href="mailto:min@mail.dk">min@email.dk</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-user-points clearfix">
            <ul>
                <li class="fa fa-heart fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart fa-3x"></li>
                <li class="fa fa-heart fa-3x"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="card-user-stats clearfix">
            <p>Sidste klip</p>
            <p class="user-last-stamp">11/11/2014</p>

            <p>Samlet klip</p>
            <p class="user-total-stamps">147</p>

            <p>kopper givet</p>
            <p class="user-total-cups">14</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <div class="btn"></div> <a href="#" class="destructive-link"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/mah93cv1/

```
$(".card .card-user-points ul").each(function() {
    var countHearts = $(this).children('.fa-heart').length;
    console.log(countHearts);

    if(countHearts == 10) {
        $(this).parent().parent().children(".card-footer").children(".btn").html( "Give Coffee" );
        $(this).parent().parent().children(".card .card-footer" ).children(".btn").addClass( "green" );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(this).closest(".card").find(".card-footer .btn").html( "Give Coffee" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting all elements with btn class in this two line

```
   $( ".card .card-footer .btn" ).html( "Give Coffee" );
   $(".card-wrapper").find( ".card .btn" ).addClass( "green" );
```

You have to select the target one, you can do it by going back to parent card of current ul element and select from its children.

```
                $(".card .card-user-points ul").each(function() {
                var countHearts = $(this).children('.fa-heart').length;
                console.log(countHearts);

                if(countHearts == 10) {
                    targetCardDiv = $(this).parents('.card');
                    targetCardDiv.find(".card-footer .btn" )
                    .addClass( "green" )
                    .html( "Give Coffee" );
                }
            });
```

Check this fiddle, I have deleted a li entry of class heart in the last card div to demonstrate that count checking works. You will see two green background 'Give Coffee' block.

http://jsfiddle.net/ibrahim12/k65zs3oe/